# Suggestions Needed for a Drawing Tablet

Tags: drawing-tablet, hardware-recommendation

My boyfriend very vaugely mentioned wanting a drawing tablet for christmas.

As a person with no artistic talent, I'm honestly at a loss. All I know is he would like one that **doesn't have to be connected to the computer** (basically so we can hang out in our living room and he can draw while his desk top is in the office) so the drawing itself needs to actually appear on the screen.

The only ones I've been able to find have been hooked up to the computer in order to see what you're drawing. And I don't necessarily want to spend an insane amount of money either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5753/how-can-i-determine-which-drawing-tablet-is-right-for-me

Comment: iPad Pro with an Apple Pencil is perfect for this. Quite pricey though.

Comment: Tablet pc's for this purpose are all kind of expensive. You may have to get one that needs to be connected to a computer ( screen or no screen ). I haven't kept myself incredibly up to date with these, but I believe you should expect tablet computers with Wacom's technology or similar quality pressure sensitive stylus to cost upwards from $600. Especially if the requirement is that it runs Windows, which I would say it should. [This site could be useful to you.](http://www.tabletsforartists.com/) I wouldn't fully trust everything that they say, but should give you good amount of information.

Answer (score 2):

For onscreen drawing, you either drift towards something expensive, or something with low precision. Like a Cintiq, an Android tablet/iPad + a pressure responsive stylus, etc.

There are some nice quality Chinese Cintiq alternatives, but they're still far above the average price of a Tablet.

---

*For not directly onscreen drawing, Wacom tablets usually are sure shot. They can be both high quality and affordable.*

*You can find one for as low as $80, or even less if you go after a used one.
The Bamboo Series (now deprecated) can be found for incredibly low prices, although its support has been discontinued, newer drivers exist for Mac but not for Windows.*

*The current equivalent is the new Intuos Family, the **CTL-470** and **480** have a fair price range and its quality is very satisfying for either pros and amateurs.*

Comment: They have Wacom Tablets that show up on the actual screen? Does it have the capability to send the drawings to a computer as well? I'm sorry if these are silly questions, like I mentioned earlier I'm no artist & I have zero knowledge about drawing tablets

Comment: unfortunately, the intuos family does not. 
for drawing directly onscreen, things starts to get costly. 
The cheapest alternative would be something like a Samsung Galaxy Note with a pressure-sensitive stylus.  I personally find quite awkward to draw at one, but this is my personal opinion.

Comment: Okay, hm.. Thanks a bunch, guess I still have some looking into to do.